# What are the thing we need to configure to implement live notification module (using redis and socket.io) in https server?

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have done a successfully live notification module in my local machine. I need to implement this module in live server. Live server is https. I don't know what are the things we need to change for https. Please check my code and help to integrate this on https server. Thanks.

**ssl files**

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.de/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.de/privkey.pem
```

**socket.js**

```
var app   = require('express')();
var http  = require('http').Server(app);
var io    = require('socket.io')(http);
var redis = require('redis');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    /* Realtime message subscribe */
    redisClient.subscribe('message');
    redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message){
        /*console.log('new message in queue', channel, message);*/
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    /* Realtime inquiry subscribe */
    redisClient.subscribe('inquiryCount');
    redisClient.on('inquiryCount', function(channel, message){
        /*console.log('new inquiry in queue', channel, message);*/
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        redisClient.quit();
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('{{env('APP_URL')}}:3000');
        /* Realtime message notification */
        socket.on('message', function(data){
           if(data){
               /* var res = $.parseJSON(data);*/
               $('.messages-menu').empty();
               $('.messages-menu').html(data);
           }
        });
        /* Realtime inquiry notification */
        socket.on('inquiryCount', function(data){
            if(data){
                $('.tasks-menu').empty();
                $('.tasks-menu').html(data);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**DashboardController.php**

```
public function privateMessageAPICount($id)
{
      $message = 'taking count of data';
      if(count($message) > 0){
           $redis = Redis::connection();
                $redis->publish('message', $message);
                return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
        }
        else {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'No Result'], 404);
        }
 }

public function inquiryAPIUnreadCount($id)
{
   $inquiryCount .= 'taking count of data';
   if(count($inquiryCount ) > 0){
         $redis = Redis::connection();
          $redis->publish('inquiryCount', $inquiryCount);
          return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
        }
        else {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'No Result'], 404);
        }              
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your apache server is already configured using https, you just have to implement https to your ws-server. Since this is a node http server, this modified code should work (based on this [post](https://medium.com/netscape/everything-about-creating-an-https-server-using-node-js-2fc5c48a8d4e)):

```
var app   = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.de/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.de/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var https  = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
var io    = require('socket.io')(https);
var redis = require('redis');


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    /* Realtime message subscribe */
    redisClient.subscribe('message');
    redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message){
        /*console.log('new message in queue', channel, message);*/
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    /* Realtime inquiry subscribe */
    redisClient.subscribe('inquiryCount');
    redisClient.on('inquiryCount', function(channel, message){
        /*console.log('new inquiry in queue', channel, message);*/
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        redisClient.quit();
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});


https.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Your `APP_URL` has to start with `https://`.

I would recommend to use [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) to handle ws-connections, it's much simpler

Comment: I had tried this code but I am getting error `ReferenceError: fs is not defined`

Comment: Now I am getting another error `ReferenceError: http is not defined`

Comment: Fixed. Sorry for not testing it. I modified your code in stackoverflow without using an ide.

Comment: Now showing port is listening. But `a user connected` console message is not showing. I have monitor redis using `redis-cli monitor`. Notification count is showing in redis. Something happend in user connection.

Comment: Is an error thrown in your browser console when you try to connect ? Have you added the https to your URL ?

Comment: Not showing any error message in console. I already added https in url.

Comment: Thank you. I will check and let you know

Comment: Yes it is a valid connection.

Comment: `require('fs')`, do we need to install this npm package?

Comment: `fs` should be a standard. Since I can't see the full code in the running environment it's seems to be impossible to find the error with this peace of information :(

Comment: The issue is firewall is blocking the 3000 port. Now your code is works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

I cant write it as a command @sam sam.

only need to do is

```
    http{
    server {
            listen       443 ssl;
            server_name  localhost;
            keepalive_timeout  5;
            proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
            proxy_send_timeout 7d;
            proxy_read_timeout 7d;

            # Self-signed certificate.
            ssl_certificate ../ssl/server.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key ../ssl/server.key;
            ssl_protocols         SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://apache_nodes/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
    }
       upstream apache_nodes {
        server 192.168.1.155;
    }

}
```

This will quarantee you to handle 443 and send client to 80 via proxy pass.

For more information please look at nginx ssl proxy server. With using the same proxy server usage , you can also handle your socket.io request over 443

for this

```
 upstream socket_nodes_1 {
        server 192.168.1.155:1337;
    }
location /sockets {
            proxy_pass http://socket_nodes_1/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

Regards,

Comment: But this is based on nginx right? I am using Apache 2.

Answer (score 3):

This is my working socket_https.js :

```
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.de/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.test.de/fullchain.pem'),
    NPNProtocols: ['http/2.0', 'spdy', 'http/1.1', 'http/1.0']
};

var server = require('https').Server(options);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);


var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('message-channel');

redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Receive');
    console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(4000);
```

Then When I want to publish to redis :

```
$data = [
      'event' => 'someEvent',
      'data'  => [
                      'id' => $id,
                      [...]
                  ]
];

Redis::publish('my-channel', json_encode($data));
```

Comment: I had tried your code but I am getting some error when I run `node socket.js`. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Redis.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/demo.laravel-api/              socket.js:22:20)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Redis.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Redis.exports.returnReply (/var/www/html/demo.laravel-api/node_modules/ioredis/lib/redis/parser.js:107:14)`

Comment: I have add my code I use to publish to redis as well

Answer (score 0):

Do not change anything on your side. Only use nginx for handling https and use proxypass on location / to the 80 port. By the way your system now supporting and working on https

Comment: I am using Apache 2. Do you know what are the things we need to configure in Apache 2?

Comment: Sam the answer is below. You can check this. for further question you can mail me